# Unable to connect to mongoDB atlas using mongoose.js

Tags: mongodb

I'm unable to connect to mongoDB atlas using mongoose.js

It is throwing the error:

```
C:\Users\uttar\Desktop\blog_application>node index.js
including files:./routes/appRoutes.js
including files:./models/BlogSchema.js
Example app listening on port 3000!
database connection error:
{ Error: querySrv ETIMEOUT _mongodb._tcp.cluster0-t3rcj.mongodb.net
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:196:19)
  errno: 'ETIMEOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEOUT',
  syscall: 'querySrv',
  hostname: '_mongodb._tcp.cluster0-t3rcj.mongodb.net' }
```

[<sup>[Here's a snapshot of the error in console]</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uw1xp.jpg)

```
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`);
    let db = mongoose.connect(mongodb+srv://amiuttar:<[password>][1]@cluster0-t3rcj.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true, {useNewUrlParser: true});

})

//handling database connection error

mongoose.connection.on('error',function (err){
    console.log("database connection error:");
    console.log(err);
})

//handling connection success

mongoose.connection.on('open',function (err){
    if(err){
        console.log("database connection error:");
        console.log(err); 
    }else{
        console.log("database connected successfully");
    }
})
```

Comment: (1) Thank you for providing the error message text as text.   In the future, please provide updates to your posts as edits rather than comments.  (2) Please describe in detail what you are doing when you get this error.   (Again, please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.)